# Split by control characters

Tags: php, parsing, split

I have a file, that has lines of data with control characters delimeted such as ^B, ^A and so on. I want to parse this data and I want to be able to split the data by the control characters?

```
split('^B',$data);
```

doesnt work for me.

How can i split this data by control characters such as ^B or ^A?

Comment: `split('\2',$data);
` this worked actually. But is that for ^B or ^A. is there a list for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the text has literal control characters, then you'd have to split on those. You're splitting on a 2-char STRING that happens to LOOK like a control character.

Try

```
split(chr(2), $data);
```

as ctrl-b is ascii 0x02;

Comment: is there a list for all the control characters?

Comment: http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/telecom/codes/ascii.html  scroll down to "ASCII Control Codes"